# How one instance Azure Function handle multiple partition event hub trigger

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have an Azure Function hosting on App service plan with Event Hub trigger. The Event Hub has 4 partitions.

My question is, if the function has only one instance, how the function process the events from 4 partitions? Does this one instance function acquire lease of all 4 partition, and round robin to process partition by partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know a single instance how to handle multiple partitions, the azure function doc has a sample about it:[Trigger - scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=csharp#scaling).

The main idea is when your function is first enabled, there is only one instance of the function, function has a single instance of EventProcessorHost that holds a lease on all ten partitions. This instance will read events from partitions 0-9.

And it list three situation **New function instances are not needed**, **An additional function instance is added** and  **N more function instances are added**.

Your requirement is one instance, in the doc it says the instance will handle all events before the Function Scaling logic take effect.

Comment: Thanks George. I read the document you shared, still have question about "handle all events" logic. Say, now I have 2 partitions, partition 0 has two 2 batches of events, p0_e0, p0_e1, partition 2 has 1 batch event: p1_e0. Can azure function guarantee p0_e0 and p1_e0 will be processed before p0_e1 is processed? That is say, azure function will handle events in breadth-first mode? (breadth here represents the partition count).

Comment: @Youxu, here is a [blog](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/in-order-event-processing-with-azure-functions-bb661eb55428) about this, the function will process message concurrently on default, however you could configure `maxBatchSize` to 1 to get the perfect order. [event hub host.json settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#hostjson-settings)

Comment: @Youxu, any update on this issue? If this could help you, please accept it as the answer.